# Angular Material UI datepicker with range support that is only 1 click?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I googled Material UI Datepicker with range support.
and I found saturn-datepicker.

Yes Saturn-datepicker is what I was looking for.
But What I want to do is that `end date` (1 week later since `begin` date) is decided automatically when I click `begin date`, not click both `begin date` and `end date`.

I thought I can catch `period` variable when `period` value has changed like below.
But `this._form.get('period').valueChanges` works after both `begin date` and `end date` has selected.

How can I set `end date` automatically after `begin date` has clicked ???

html

```
<div class="m-form__control">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Period" [satDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="period">
    <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"></sat-datepicker>
    <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

component

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilderService) {
  this._form = this.fb.build(this.onDestroy$);
  this._form
    .get('period')
    .valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
    .subscribe((value) => console.log('value = ', value));
}
```

FormBuilderService

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

build(onDestroy$: Observable<never>): FormGroup {
    const now = moment();
    const end = now.toDate();
    const weekAgo = moment(now).subtract(7, 'days');
    const begin = weekAgo.toDate();
    return this.fb.group({
        period: [{ begin: begin, end: end }],
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with npm install saturn-datepicker. See their [Github page](https://github.com/SaturnTeam/saturn-datepicker) for full integration instructions.

#### Template

```html
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
        placeholder="Choose a date"
        [satDatepicker]="picker"
        [value]="date">
    <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"></sat-datepicker>
    <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: this is not an answer. It doesn't answer the op's question

Comment: thank you for your answer @Savaj Patel. but I already installed it. What I want to do is how to customize saturn-datepicker.